# How to create optimized java online compiler?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to create an online Java compiler for my coding website. A user submits the code that will be compiled and run against the testcases (steps in a single job). My code runs one job after another, while the remaining jobs are waiting in the queue. I have sent 10 requests in a second, but only a few of them were successfully completed. Others give the following types of errors:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
at java.lang.Thread.start0(java.base/Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(java.base/Thread.java:798)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.<clinit>(java.base/Finalizer.java:187)
```

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit
```

Sometimes a file(hs_err_pid2185.log) containing below message also gets created by JVM.

```
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Unscaled Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 4GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 4GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (workerManager.hpp:70), pid=2185, tid=2189
#
# JRE version:  (11.0.15+10) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.15+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/project/core.2185)
```

Clearly, the problem is related to memory. I was using Docker to run the application on an EC2 instance with 8GB of memory. When I checked the memory usage through *Docker stats*, I found it was not even using 10% of the total RAM.

Solutions I tried:

- jlink - to reduce size of jvm, which also is giving similar results.
- nailgun - JVM server. No clear documentation. So, i was not able to run it properly.
- drip - JVM server. It was buggy.
- Increasing the ram of EC2 instance.

**What is the reason for this behavior? What is the maximum capacity of the JVM in this case? What are the solutions or methods that coding platforms like Hackerrank use?**

Comment: What JVM options are you using?

Comment: Does the error occur right when starting java or while running?

Comment: @StephenC I'm not giving any such options

Comment: @dan1st While Running

Comment: What external limits are placed on the JVM's memory usage; e.g. using via docker or `ulimit`.

Comment: @StephenC None.

Comment: Run this inside the docker container and tell us what it says: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -Ei "maxheapsize|maxram"`